# Proper async looping in console app

Tags: c#, async-await

I know async I/O doesn't bring parallelism but I thought when the app is awaiting an async operation it *could* carry on doing other stuff.

Consider the below code I would expect the loop to carry on while awaiting Wait(i) but obviously I was wrong and each iteration is blocking. What's the correct way to achieve some concurrency here?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace asynctest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Do().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public static async Task Do()
        {   
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {
                await Wait(i);
            }
        }

        public static async Task Wait(int i)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what `await` do. It suspends the loop to make your concurrent code run sequentially.

Comment: await generally blocks operation to wait for other operation to complete. But here it  seems blocking every iteration because each iteration is taking almost the same amount of time. You could have understand the difference if you would put different type of tasks in a Task array and process the array index with await operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public static async Task Do()
{
    var tasks = new Task[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        tasks[i] = Wait(i);
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `WhenAll()` to combine the task results, thus your tasks will run in parallel:

```
namespace asynctest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Do().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }

        public static async Task Do()
        {   
            for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
            {

              var task1 = Wait(5000);
              var task2 = Wait(3000);   
              int[] result = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
              Console.WriteLine("waited for a total of " + result.Sum() + " ms");          
            }
        }

        public static async Task<int> Wait(int i)
        {
            await Task.Delay(i);
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```